# Formar tablero buscaminas

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola a todos y gracias de antemano.

Estoy intentando hacer un busca minas muy básico, pero primero tengo que dibujar el "tablero" y estoy un poco atascado con eso. Lo estoy haciendo con swing de Java. Con un Jframe y dentro dos Jpanel, uno en el que le introduzco las filas y columnas que va a poseer el tablero y un botón que llama a un método que dibuja los botones de manera automática, pero no consigo que me dibuje los botones, ya he probado que el código cree los botones y los crea, pero junto al método, no los crea. adjunto fragmento de código del método a ver si me podéis echar una mano.

```
public void ponbotones(int filas, int columnas){
    int pintar = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<filas; i++){
        JButton boton = new JButton(i+"");
        boton.setLocation(60*i, pintar);
        boton.setVisible(true);
        boton.setSize(50, 15);
        panel.add(boton);
    }
    for(int j=0; j<this.columnas-1; j++){
        pintar += 25;
        for(int k=0; k<filas; k++){
            JButton boton = new JButton(k+"");
            boton.setLocation(60*k, pintar);
            boton.setVisible(true);
            boton.setSize(50, 15);
            panel.add(boton);
        }
    }
    this.setContentPane(panelIntroduccion);
    pintar++;
}
```

Comment: Debes añadir el código completo . recuerde leer [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jpPrincipal.setVisible(true);
        botones = new JButton[filas][columnas];
         for(filas=0; filas<botones.length;filas++){
             for(columnas=0; columnas<botones.length; columnas++){
                  JButton boton = new JButton();
                  boton.addActionListener(this);
                  botones[filas][columnas] = boton;
                  //botones[filas][columnas].setName(""+filas+columnas);

                  boton.setText("["+filas+","+columnas+"]");
                  botones[filas][columnas].setBounds(70, 30, 50, 30);

                  jpJuego.setBounds(400, 100, 300, 300);

                  jpJuego.add(botones[filas][columnas]);

             }
         }
    this.setContentPane(jpJuego);
```

Comment: muy buena respuesta :)